# PHP in Docker with NTLM-proxy: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, ipv6, ntlm

I have Windows-10 with Docker 18.06.0-ce-win72 (19098).
In our network uses NTLM-proxy, so docker goes to the Internet through **Ntlmaps** (I also try **Cntlm**, result is the same).
I run image based on php:7.2-fpm with docker-compose.
I enter the conteiner

```
docker exec -it {id} bash
```

and run command:

```
curl https://packagist.org/packages.json // works!
```

or

```
wget https://packagist.org/packages.json // works!
```

But

```
php -r "echo file_get_contents('https://packagist.org/packages.json');"
```

results "**failed to open stream: Cannot assign requested address in Command line code on line 1**"

```
curl https://packagist.org/packages.json ----> works
php -r "echo file_get_contents('https://packagist.org/packages.json');" ----------> fails to open stream
php -r "echo curl_exec(curl_init('https://packagist.org/packages.json'));" ---------> works
```

I see ntlmaps-console and view request from "curl", but it's no requests in console from "file_get_contents".

In php **allow_url_open** => **on**

I found similar problem: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2169

But I can't disable IPv6 in Docker for test the solution.

I try run "**sysctl**", but "**bash: sysctl: command not found**"

I try set

```
sysctls:
  - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
  - net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
  - net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

in docker-compose.yml for service, but it didn't solve the problem

I run this container on VPS and this work on VPS.

How can I solve this problem on Windows + NTLM?

My docker-compose.yml: https://pastebin.com/PfsgzrLs

Answer (score 1):

Solution for file_get_contents():

```
    $context = stream_context_create([
        'http' => [
            'proxy' => 'tcp://10.0.75.1:3112', // 3112 - proxy port on host-mashine
            'request_fulluri' => true
        ]
    ]);

    echo file_get_contents('https://ya.ru', false, $context);
```