# file_get_contents failed to open stream: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: php, nginx, php-7

When I try to pass a url to file_get_contents I get this

> **Warning**:
> file_get_contents(http://localhost:8001/els/get_data_from_radius.php?id=1&u=GERONIMO-ANGELA-GLADIS-17010-16407&p=5T7U5756876O93FPG7F2B56B89359488&s=1&action=2&ud=524288/5242880):
> failed to open stream: Cannot assign requested address in
> **/var/local/entropia/model/MonitoreoRadiusWrapper.php** on line
> **108**

My function is

```
public static function activar_servicio($ws_host, $id_rad, $user, $pass, $simultaneo, $ud_mikrotik) {
    $url = $ws_host . ":8001/els/get_data_from_radius.php?id=$id_rad&u=$user&p=$pass&s=$simultaneo&action=2&ud=$ud_mikrotik";

    $result = file_get_contents($url);

    return json_decode($result);
}
```

I'm using php 7 inside a docker container with nginx.

Comment: If this is using any sort of proxy, you might need to specify that via a stream context you pass to file_get_contents, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53185479/1427878

Comment: Is `8001` the internally or externally exposed Docker port? Also, is there a reason that your code is making an API call to itself? Could you instead just use the actual logic without an extra HTTP request?

Comment: 8001 is the external port. I don't really know if there's a reason for this. I'm new to this project.

Answer (score 6):

Edit:
As Sven Tore mentioned in the comment, using `host.docker.internal` should be the preferred way of referencing other running containers.
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host

If your `$ws_host` is set to `http://localhost` then the docker image will try to query it's own `localhost` and not the other container. Try changing `http://localhost` to your Host Computer's private IP. Example `http://10.0.0.8`.
This ip needs to be your computer's private IP address from the `en0.inet` value returned from `ifconfig` on Mac. For other operating systems you will need to look up how to find your computer's private IP address.

Comment: Thanks.. it helped me! I could find my private IP address using: ipconfig value of: IPv4 Address.

Comment: Consider using http://host.docker.internal, easier when switching between computers/networks with different IPs
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds-for-all-platforms